# R categories based on a part of text

Tags: r

In R I want to make categories based in text with numbers. But I want to do this based on a specific part of the text.

For example when the text is like

- search | Location | Value
- search | Radius | Value

I know that I can code this in categories with

```
ffclean$Campaign2[ffclean$Campaign=="Search | location| value"] <- 0
```

But does somebody know how to code this when you only looking for the word location?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grepl` to search for a particular word, or part of a word:

```
grepl("Location", ffclean$Campaign)
```

will give you all rows where `Campaign` contains the exact phrase 'Location'. You can add `ignore.case = TRUE` if you want to capture both 'Location', 'location' and 'LOcation'.
If you want to make a variable with categories, I would strongly advise to keep the original variable as it is, and make a new variable for the code  - that way it is easier to check that you categories are in fact as you wanted them to be. Example, here we define a new variable `Campaign2_coded`:

```
# Make data
ffclean <- data.frame(
  Campaign2 = c("Search | Location | Value", 
                "Search | Radius | Value", 
                "LOcation | Value"))

# Define new variable (with no values yet)
ffclean$Campaign2_coded <- NA    

# Do the coding:

# Values containing 'location' => code 0  
my_selection <- grepl("location", ffclean$Campaign, ignore.case = TRUE)  # select
ffclean$Campaign2_coded[my_selection] <- 0                               # set code    

# Other values (! means "everything else") => code 1  
ffclean$Campaign2_coded[!my_selection] <- 1
```

Many people like to use the `dplyr` (tidyverse) syntax, using `mutate` and [case_when](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html):

```
ffclean <- ffclean %>%
  mutate(
    Campaign2_coded = case_when(
       grepl("location", ffclean$Campaign, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ 0,  # set code = 0
       TRUE ~ 1)     # set code = 1 for everything else
    )
```